# Are mung beans grown in Japan or North America?

Tags: chinese-cuisine

My grandparents in Toronto need green mung beans to make Chinese [green bean soup dessert](https://www.rotinrice.com/sweet-mung-bean-and-sago-soup/) (another [recipe](https://en.christinesrecipes.com/2011/11/sweet-green-mung-bean-soup-hong-kong.html)). But they've found only ones [from China](https://www.yupik.ca/en/our-products/cooking/beans/organic-mung-beans.html). They prefer to buy locally, and  are too frightened by China's [countless food safety incidents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Food_safety_incidents_in_China#Dyed_green_beans) to buy foods from China.

Comment: If you search for moong or mung dal you should be able to find Indian produced ones, just watch out for the yellow variety. I also found [these](https://www.amazon.com/California-Grown-Organic-Mung-Beans/dp/B01D1T3A7Q?th=1)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know any sources in Canada, but you can buy [mung beans grown in Oregon](https://www.bobsredmill.com/mung-beans.html?gclid=EAIaIQobChMIq9DP9-v73wIVGYrICh3pMQ3VEAQYAiABEgIfx_D_BwE) [or California](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01D1T3A7Q) fairly easily.